# Calculate mean number of rows per item per month in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I had trouble finding a clear, generic way of phrasing this question, so apologies if it's a repeat. Here's the situation:

I have a table recording collaborative tagging data, with each row storing an annotation (i.e. a particular user tagging a particular item with a particular tag at a particular time). Here's a sample for clarity:

```
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| user_id | item_id | tag_id | tag_month  |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| 1040740 |    2653 |   1344 | 2005-07-01 |
| 1040740 |    3602 |   1344 | 2005-07-01 |
| 1040740 |   17746 |    217 | 2005-07-01 |
| 1040740 |   21426 |   1344 | 2005-07-01 |
| 1040740 |   22224 |    180 | 2005-07-01 |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
```

...and so on. What I'm trying to calculate is, on a month-by-month basis, the mean number of annotations per item, across all items. In other words, for each month, what is the average number of rows per unique item for that month? My dataset spans 94 total months, so the output of the query I'm wanting should be 94 rows, each with average number of annotations per item for that month. Note that the "user_id" column is completely irrelevant to this.

Comment: Does everything need 94 rows even if there are zero annotations for that item in that month?

Comment: So every row will have the exact same number (the average for ALL items combined) or just the average for that specific item (which will just be the count for that item_id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight deviation to Alma Do Mundo's answer to give the average number of tags per item per month.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) as tag_average,
  YEAR(tag_month),
  MONTH(tag_month)
FROM
  t
GROUP BY
  YEAR(tag_month),
  MONTH(tag_month)
```

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. Didn't make this clear, but splitting into columns by year and month unnecessary because data is already segregated into months (i.e. query functions perfectly for me as: "SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) as tag_average, tag_month FROM t GROUP BY tag_month".

Comment: Because the sample data includes the day of the month, I (and I suppose @Alma Do Mundo) wasn't sure about tag_month representing just a year and a month. Anyways, glad it works. Alma Do Mundo deserves credit for getting the ball rolling.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need just to do the corresponding COUNT's:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT item_id),
  YEAR(tag_month),
  MONTH(tag_month)
FROM
  t
GROUP BY
  YEAR(tag_month),
  MONTH(tag_month)
```

not sure if you want to get `item_id`, but, if you need, then:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(1),
  item_id,
  YEAR(tag_month),
  MONTH(tag_month)
FROM
  t
GROUP BY
  item_id,
  YEAR(tag_month),
  MONTH(tag_month)
```

Comment: Here's a SQLFiddle to go with this (assuming he does just want each item's individual average, count in this case): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f15871/4

Comment: "COUNT(DISTINCT item_id)" gives the number of items affected. "COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT item_id)" will give the average number of tags per item for the month.

Comment: Accepted @gwc's answer instead, as this gives counts not averages.